# Postgres format join lookup so it returns a single object

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables, Products & Features. I am trying to make it so that all of the features are a property of the Product object but I am instead getting multiple product objects each with one of the features attached it.

Query:
`SELECT * FROM products JOIN features ON products.id = features.product_id WHERE products.id = ${id};`

Returns:
Note: The product.id in this example is 5, and id attached is from the features table (which I don't want included)

```
[
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Heir Force Ones",
    "slogan": "A sneaker dynasty",
    "description": "Super long description...",
    "category": "Kicks",
    "default_price": 99,
    "product_id": 5,
    "feature": "Sole",
    "value": "Rubber"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    ### same product object ###
    "feature": "Material",
    "value": "FullControlSkin"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    ### same product object ###
    "feature": "Mid-Sole",
    "value": "ControlSupport Arch Bridge"
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    ### same product object ###
    "feature": "Stitching",
    "value": "Double Stitch"
  }
]
```

What I would like for it to return is:

```
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Heir Force Ones",
    "slogan": "A sneaker dynasty",
    "description": "Super long description...",
    "category": "Kicks",
    "default_price": 99,
    features: [
                {
                 "feature": "Sole",
                 "value": "Rubber"
                },
                {
                 "feature": "Material",
                 "value": "FullControlSkin"
                },
                {
                 "feature": "Mid-Sole",
                 "value": "ControlSupport Arch Bridge"
                 },
                {
                 "feature": "Stitching",
                 "value": "Double Stitch"
                }
              ]
  }
```

Any idea how I can combine them into 1 object?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve using this method but not sure how efficient it is.

```
  const id = req.params.id;

  const features = client
    .query(`SELECT feature, value FROM features WHERE product_id = ${id};`)
    .then((data) => data.rows)
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  const product = client
    .query(`SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ${id};`)
    .then((data) => data.rows[0])
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  Promise.all([product, features])
    .then( result => {
      let [product, features] = result;
      product.features = features
      res.send(product);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```